# Apache change favicon for certain directory

Tags: apache, favicon

I'm having a problem with apache that it only looks in the root directory for favicons. I need a separate favicon for a specific directory on my webpage. Below I will draw an example

```
- favicon.ico
- index.html
- / Folder
  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - index2.html
```

I want `/index.html` to have a favicon of `/favicon.ico` and I want `/Folder/index.html` and `/Folder/index.html2` to have a favicon of `/Folder/favicon.ico`. (Edit: I do not want to specify at the top of each file, there are too many to make that practical)

I tried just putting a favicon.ico inside the sub-folder but it didn't do anything different. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following code to the `<head>` element of each HTML file were you want to change the icon:

`<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">`

**The Path needs to be adapted in the code snippet**
What is important is that you have this snippet in your HTML files and then you just update the path to the icon you want.

This link might help you:
https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-add-a-favicon-in-html

Also if you search google for your problem you will get many docs and examples.

Comment: What if in `/Folder` I were to have more than one file? It would be too much work to do that to each. Is there a way I can set it for the whole directory?

Comment: I am more of a mobile dev acutally and not very familiar with this sort of thing but maybe you can use some sort of Middleware(Maybe overpowered)